# How to progress the echo from 1 to 100% in bash in given time?

Tags: bash

Iam using a bash script which i want to show a timer before my next function should called.So instead of regular `sleep 5` i wanted to use some progress bar.So from stackoverflow I found this snippet.

```
for pc in $(seq 1 10); do
    echo -ne "$pc%\033[0K\r"
    sleep 1
done
```

But this only shows 1 to 10% in `10` seconds . But all I need is to move the progress bar from 1 to 100 in `10 Seconds` like `0 10 20 ... 90 100` Just like the above script.

Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for pc in $(seq 0 10 100); do
    echo -ne "$pc%\033[0K\r"
    sleep 1
done
```

This will start from 0 and proceed to 100 with steps of 10